# why does the function skip the padding on the first call?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

void go_lower(char *str);
void fill_str(char *mass);

int main()
{
    char str_1[80];
    char str_2[80];
    char *pointer_1;
    char *pointer_2;

    pointer_1 = str_1;
    pointer_2 = str_2;

    fill_str(pointer_1);

    fill_str(pointer_2);

    if(strcmp(str_1, str_2))
    {
        std::cout << "This strings are equal\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "This strings are not equal\n";
    }


    return 0;
}

void fill_str(char *mass)
{
    std::cout << "Insert string to compare\n";
    while(*mass)
    {
        std::cin >> *mass;

        mass++;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}


void go_lower(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if(isupper(*str))
        {
            *str = tolower(*str);
        }

        str++;
    }
}
```

Not so long ago I started studying programming and I try to understand the test tasks. In this program, I need to compare strings regardless of the case of the characters. when the program starts, it goes straight to filling in str_2 and the comparison block concludes that the strings are equal. What is the error?

Comment: Just what do you think `while(*mass)` is doing? How will you know when to stop reading characters? You have only `80` characters available. You can't read a nul-terminating character directly (unless you have redirected a binary file on `stdin` as input) Further, since `str_1` and `str_2` are uninitialized, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* with the comparison itself - attempting to access the value of a variable with automatic storage duration while its value is indeterminate.

Comment: When `while(*mass)` is evaluated,  `*mass` is uninitialized data. Quite possibly it's zero and exits the function immediately. Otherwise, it's likely going to be an infinite loop since it's hard for a user to type `'\0'` into the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in C++, you should really use [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you still need to know how to handle plain-old-arrays. When passing an plain-old-array to a function to be filled, you must pass an additional parameter to provide the array size to the function. Within the function you can only read `size - 2` characters into the array (saving index `size - 1` for the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (ASCII `0`).

You should also avoid using *MagicNumbers* in your code. Instead, if you need a constant (such as for `80`), `#define` a constant or use a `const int` in C++. Since you have a choice for your return type, you should return the number of characters read into each string. The information will be available when you leave your `fill_str()` function and there is no reason to have to calling function re-scan for end-of-string.

You cannot use `std::cin` effectively to read multi-word input in a function as you are attempting. `std::cin` discards whitespace, so you will never read the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>[Enter]</kbd>. So you have know way to know when the user is done typing. Instead you must use `std::cin.get()`; which will read every character.

With those changes, you can write your function to use plain-old-arrays as follows:

```
#define MAXC 80     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
/* using plain-old-arrays, you must pass size of array */
size_t fill_str (char *mass, size_t size)
{
    size_t n = 0;   /* length counter */
    
    std::cout << "\nInsert string to compare\n";
    
    while (n < size - 1)                                /* read while array not full */
    {
        if ((*mass = std::cin.get()) && *mass != '\n')  /* use get() to read whitespace */
            n++;                    /* increment length counter */
        
        if (*mass == '\n')          /* if \n user pressed [Enter], input complete */
            break;
        
        mass++;                     /* increment pointer */
    }
    
    *mass = 0;                      /* nul-terminate when you leave read-loop */
    
    return n;                       /* return length */
}
```

Your example, omitting your unused `go_lower()` function, could then be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXC 80     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

size_t fill_str (char *mass, size_t size);

int main (void)
{
    char str_1[MAXC];
    char str_2[MAXC];
    char *pointer_1;
    char *pointer_2;
    size_t len_1, len_2;

    pointer_1 = str_1;
    pointer_2 = str_2;

    len_1 = fill_str (pointer_1, MAXC);
    len_2 = fill_str (pointer_2, MAXC);
    
    if (len_1 != len_2) {
        std::cout << "\nstrings differ in length (" << 
                    len_1 << " != " << len_2 << ").\n";
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (strcmp (str_1, str_2) == 0)             /* only equal if return is 0 */
    {
        std::cout << "\nThis strings are equal\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nThis strings are not equal\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

/* using plain-old-arrays, you must pass size of array */
size_t fill_str (char *mass, size_t size)
{
    size_t n = 0;   /* length counter */
    
    std::cout << "\nInsert string to compare\n";
    
    while (n < size - 1)                                /* read while array not full */
    {
        if ((*mass = std::cin.get()) && *mass != '\n')  /* use get() to read whitespace */
            n++;                    /* increment length counter */
        
        if (*mass == '\n')          /* if \n user pressed [Enter], input complete */
            break;
        
        mass++;                     /* increment pointer */
    }
    
    *mass = 0;                      /* nul-terminate when you leave read-loop */
    
    return n;                       /* return length */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/golower

Insert string to compare
apples and bananas

Insert string to compare
apples and bananas

This strings are equal
```

```
$ ./bin/golower

Insert string to compare
pickle

Insert string to compare
pickles

strings differ in length (6 != 7).
```

As mentioned at the beginning, you should really use `std::string` and `getline()` to read the user input, but you should also be familiar with plain-old-arrays. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `while (*mass)` in your `fill_str` function will not loop even once because `* mass` may be initialized to `0` here (it is actually undefined behavior and up to your compiler). Because of this none of your strings will ever get filled with anything.

`strcmp` evaluates your strings equal because they are initialized in such a way they are equal from the beginning and are never changed because of the reason stated above.

To read a string consider using [`getline`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) or `std::cin` if you know that your string will not contain spaces, eg.

```cpp
std::cin >> mass;
```

See more here https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io. Also consider using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.